# Proper grammar for const reference

Tags: c++, reference, language-lawyer

I see some code like:

```
Foo const& foo = val; // (A)
const Foo& foo = val; // (B)
```

Just different placement of `const`.

Though both will work fine, I would just want to know the proper grammar.

I read it as follows from R->L.

(A) foo is a `const` reference to type `Foo` - not sure if `val` is `const`
(B) foo is a reference to `const` type `Foo` - meaning `val` is `const`

Given that references are not objects, and technically all references are `const` (they can't *refer to* another object),

**Grammar perspective**, is (A) `Foo const& foo = val;` considered a "confusing" definition?

And just use the following instead:

```
const Foo& foo = val; // referring to const Foo
Foo& foo = val;       // referring to non-const Foo
```

Comment: Since they are the same from the language perspective, question on which one to use becomes opinion-based.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`const` applies to the thing on its left, unless nothing is there, then it applies to the thing on its right instead.

These two statements are *identical*:

```
Foo const& foo = val; // (A)
const Foo& foo = val; // (B)
```

They both mean the same thing:

`foo` is a non-`const` <sup>(1)</sup> reference to a `const Foo` object, and is being initialized as a reference to an object named `val`.

<sup>(1)</sup>: by definition, a reference can't be changed once initialized, so `const` vs non-`const` doesn't really apply to a reference itself, as it is implicitly `const`.  But `const` does apply to the thing that is being referenced.

Answer (score 2):

```
Foo const& foo = val; // (A)
const Foo& foo = val; // (B)
```

Both are identical definitions and are just a matter of style:
reference to const object.

it would be different for:

```
const Foo* fooC = nullptr; // (C)
Foo* const fooD = nullptr; // (D)
```

You cannot reassign `fooD` but you can reassign `fooC`.
Object pointed by `fooC` cannot be modified through `fooC`.
Object pointed by `fooD` can be modified through `fooD`.

Comment: Those aren't analogs. The analog of `Foo const& foo` is `Foo const* ptr`. `Foo *const ptr` would correspond to `Foo &const ptr`, which is not allowed.

Comment: @rici: replacing reference by pointer, I didn't say that (D) is identical to (A) or (B) ((C) would be). I just wanted to show an other place where to put `const`. As `Foo& const foo` is not valid, I show it with pointer.

Comment: `reference to const object` - const reference to an object, to be precise.

Answer (score 0):

They're identical grammatically. And

> I read it as follows from R->L.
>
> (A) foo is a `const` reference to type `Foo`

I think you didn't read it correctly. It should be something like

```
Foo const &
Foo/const/reference to
```

then you should get "reference to const Foo`. So when reading from R->L, (A) is more clear.